# Google analytics not showing any data of android studio project

Tags: android-studio, google-analytics

I followed https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ to implement google analytics in my android app. But it is not showing any data.
Can anyone help?
Manifest file:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".AnalyticsApplication">
        <activity android:name="com.xxx.xxxx.SplashScreen" 
       android:screenOrientation="portrait">
       <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.xxx.xxxx.LoginScreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.xxx.xxxx.ForgotPasswordScreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.xx.xxx.SignupScreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.xxx.xxx.HomeScreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.xxx.xxxx.SplashScreen" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

            <meta-data

    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
                android:resource="@xml/global_tracker"/>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

AnalyticsApplication

```
    public class AnalyticsApplication  extends Application {

    private static GoogleAnalytics sAnalytics;
    private static Tracker mTracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    }

    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        if (mTracker == null) {
            mTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }

        return mTracker;
    }
    }
```

HomeScreen

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
        Helper.printLog(tag, "onCreate");

        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) 
        getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

        mTracker.setScreenName("home screen");
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
     }
     onclick(){
     mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory("Action account")
                    .setAction("account clicked")
                    .build());
           changeFragment(new AccountFragment());
    }
```

app-gradle

```
 dependencies{
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'}
```

project-gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

}
```

Comment: can anyone pls tell me my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try firebase analytics firebase is a google product to build high quality apps and its uses Google Analytics. Firebase and google analytics are same

Visit - https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/
Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your reply.